# How to differentiate apple tv and other devices in airplay?

Tags: ios, xcode, airplay, apple-tv

I am trying to connect apple tv through airplay, but the issue is some time if i connect any other external device like bluetooth or some other device it shows like device connected in window. So i want to identify which device is connected i have to enable only when apple tv is connected.

How can i identify whether it is apple tv or some other device?

This how i create airplay custom button

```
  for (UIButton *button in volumeView.subviews) {
            if ([button isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
                self.airplayButton = (UIButton*)button;
                button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 23);
                button.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                [self.airplayButton addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"alpha" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];

            }

        }
```

So the alpha always changes for button even some other devices gets connected.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a look into this before, there's no easily provided way of determining whether the attached device is an Apple TV, there is a Airplay Picker which does this but the code/functions behind it don't seem to be available.

The best you can do it monitor for additional screens being added/removed and then showing your external content only when the screen has the capabilities to do what you need.

I have read somewhere previously that you can get the capabilities of an airplay device and use this information to detect an Apple TV but unfortunately I cannot find it at the moment. If I do find it I'll add a comment.

For now, your best option would be to use the concepts described in this [guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/WindowAndScreenGuide/UsingExternalDisplay/UsingExternalDisplay.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012555-CH3-SW1)

The code provided is in objective-c but its very easily converted to swift, here is the main part you should be looking at

```
- (void)checkForExistingScreenAndInitializeIfPresent

{

    if ([[UIScreen screens] count] > 1)

    {

        // Get the screen object that represents the external display.

        UIScreen *secondScreen = [[UIScreen screens] objectAtIndex:1];

        // Get the screen's bounds so that you can create a window of the correct size.

        CGRect screenBounds = secondScreen.bounds;



        self.secondWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:screenBounds];

        self.secondWindow.screen = secondScreen;



        // Set up initial content to display...

        // Show the window.

        self.secondWindow.hidden = NO;

    }

}
```

Like I said you can code this so that it checks the device supports certain resolutions so you can rule out devices that wont support your UI

Some additional resources: https://developer.apple.com/airplay/